# -bash: cd: tomcat: Permission denied

Tags: tomcat, centos

How can I access the tomcat folder to stop that instance. Its always giving me error

```
-bash: cd: tomcat: Permission denied
```

whenver I am trying to access it via

```
sudo -i cd /opt/tomcat
```

I dont have root's user/pw for my centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if that command did work, it would only `cd` into the directory while the shell spawned by `sudo` was running.  In effect what you'd get is:

```
$ pwd
/home/ian
$ sudo -i cd /opt/tomcat
$ pwd
/home/ian
```

Instead, start an interactive shell as `root` and run your commands:

```
$ sudo su -
# cd /opt/tomcat
# ...
# exit
$
```